# Count print pages on a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to understand how many printing pages an excel worksheet extends programatically?

I make same documents automatically. But if the document would have contain more than one page it must be created afresh.

Is there any way to get the total number of print pages after create the document programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PageBreaks will do the trick! ;)

```
Public Function Printed_Pages_Count(wS as Worksheet) As Integer
    Printed_Pages_Count = (wS.HPageBreaks.Count + 1) * (wS.VPageBreaks.Count + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: @kitapmitap : Glad I could help! How about accepting my answer? ;)

Comment: @kitapmitap : Ahaha ok, I was too fast! ;)